# NSFetchedResultsController does not show latest items added in relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to show items in `UITableView` using `NSFetchedResultsController` but when I add items from background thread then tableview does not show changes until I go back to other screen and come again.

I also found that if I call `[_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];` in `contextChanged:` method then it shows updated thing in the table.

Now the issue is why it is not showing new added items by itself.

```
- (void)contextChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if ([notification object] == [self managedObjectContext])
        return;

    if (![NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(contextChanged:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }

    if (self.managedObjectContext!=nil)
    {
        [[self managedObjectContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }
}

----------


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSString *userId=[Shared getLoginUserId];
    if (userId==nil || [userId isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        userId=@"0";
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"WhatNext" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

     NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(selectedByUser,$x,$x.user_id == %@).@count > 0", [[Shared getLoginUserIdElseZero] toNSNumber]];

    NSLog(@"todo Predicate -- %@",predicate);
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    //    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"localOrderNo" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"todoFavoritesOrderNo" ascending:YES];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sort2]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:kToDoCacheName];
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:nil];

    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using the nsfetchedresultscontroller delegate methods to make table updates?

Comment: yes, i am using delegate methods

Comment: do you have the bg MOC setup as a child to the main thread MOC?